# Angular 7 inject a dynamic component into the template

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code. When ***ngOnInit()*** runs, ***this.widget*** contains the correct component and ***this.data*** contains the appropriate data.

I was unable to figure our how to smoothly insert the dynamic component into the template, so that the result will be the equivalent of ***<DynamicComponent [data]="data"></DynamicComponent>***, where ***DynamicComponent*** is the component referenced in ***this.widget***.

I tried a few online examples, but couldn't get them to work. Can anyone help?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IdashService } from '../services/idash.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-idash-widget',
  template: `
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 *ngIf="widgetConfig.title" class="card-title">{{widgetConfig.title}}</h5>

      <!-- I want the component here with the [data] attribute set to this.data -->

    </div>            
  `
})

export class IdashWidgetComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() widgetConfig;
  widget;
  data;

  constructor(private idashService: IdashService) {
    this.data = {
      someKey: 'someValue'
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.widget = this.idashService.moduleConfig.widgets[this.widgetConfig.type];
    console.warn(this.widget, this.data)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to see if it work

```
<template #dynamicContainer></template>
```

And in your component

```
@ViewChild("dynamicContainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
componentRef: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent>;
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

createComponent(type) {
    //Clear the container.
    this.container.clear();
    //Create a factory for component.
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    //Create a component using the factory
    this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
    //Pass the value for @Input properties using a component reference instance method.
    this.componentRef.instance.data = this.data;
}
```

In your module make sure to add your component to your entryComponents array like this

```
entryComponents: [GaugeComponent]
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot, your help is much appreciated. Second: I get the following error message:

Error: No component factory found for GaugeComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError 
...
I assume the component needs some special handling, but what does it mean?

Comment: Check my answer again. Forget to add into module

Comment: Although @tony-ngo's answer is 100% correct, I've faced some situations (that I can't remember right now) that pushed me to use `@angular/cdk/portal`. There are some additional checks in this library that decreases the chances of you messing up with the things. Take a look in the docs: https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Comment: @TonyNgo - I'm afraid not. Still getting Error: No component factory found for GaugeComponent. Adding the components to ModuleWithProviders under entryComponents still results in this error